# Come si chiama il cartellone "ad A" che molti bar piazzano sul marciapiede?

Tags: phrase-request, vocabulary, nouns

Ho improvvisamente notato che non ho idea di come si chiami il tipico "cartellone" che si usa mettere fuori dai bar, sul marciapiede, che in genere sui due lati ha una lavagna (o simile superficie per scrivere).

[image: esempio]

Comment: “Lavagna su cavalletto”?

Comment: @egreg ah ok, non ha un nome specifico dunque!

Comment: Non ne ho mai sentito uno, forse altri possono aiutare di più.

Comment: A quanto pare, commercialmente si chiama [«cavalletto bifacciale»](https://www.google.it/?gws_rd=ssl#q=cavalletto+bifacciale).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Commercialmente si chiama ***[lavagna mono o sandwich](https://www.google.it/#q=+lavagna+sandwitch+o+mono+)***  a seconda che abbia una singola facciata o due a cavalletto come nella foto:

[image: lavagna sandwich]